Error: solders.SignerError: not enough signers
I am trying to buy a token through solana.ру, but in the process of writing the code, I get an error
from solana.rpc.api import Client, Keypair, Pubkey
from spl.token.constants import TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
from spl.token.client import Token

wallet_secret_key = Keypair.from_bytes([227,...,52]) 
wallet_public_key = Pubkey.from_string("6vp...Kyu") 
target_spl_mint = Pubkey.from_string('3Pd...br9')
amount_to_buy = 1000 
program_id = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID

client = Client('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com')
    

token = Token(conn=client, pubkey=target_spl_mint,program_id=program_id,payer=wallet_secret_key)
blockhash = client.get_latest_blockhash().value.blockhash
    
#The error is here 
transaction = token.mint_to(recent_blockhash=blockhash,dest=wallet_public_key,mint_authority=target_spl_mint,amount=amount_to_buy)
    
tx_id = client.send_transaction(transaction, wallet_secret_key)
print(f"Транзакция отправлена. ID: {tx_id}")


Error
    self._solders.sign(signers, self._solders.message.recent_blockhash)
solders.SignerError: not enough signers

I'm just at the beginning of learning solana and spl.token. If I have chosen the wrong method to purchase tokens for sol, please let me know.
Thank You

Since you're using the mint_to command on the client, you're not buying tokens, you're trying to create new tokens. Only the mint authority has the ability to create new tokens on a mint.
If you want to trade SOL for other tokens, you need to use some on-chain trading protocol, like an automated market-maker (AMM) or a central limit order book (CLOB). I won't recommend particular products here, but you can do some research on AMMs and CLOBs on Solana. Once you learn about them, you can look into any dev libraries that they may have in order to trade the tokens that interest you.
